# Lock map but keep pushpins available

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a bing map in my application which users can lock using the following function:

```
private void btnLock_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  if (btnLock == null || btnLock.IsChecked == null) {
    return;
  }
  map.IsHitTestVisible = !btnLock.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

Now, when I have pushpins on the map, i want the users to be able to click on them still, but that's not possible when the map is locked. How do i prevent the users from dragging the map but keep them enabled to click the pushpins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be nice if there were a bool property you could just set to false, but it looks like that doesn't exist. How about this?

> You can disable the related panning and zooming functions by handling the doubleclick, drag, etc events from the map and setting e.Handled = true.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/4e1ee9f7-5445-41c6-8685-0b058c42c894

I haven't tried it, but I imagine for Windows Phone you'd handle events like MapPan, Tap, DoubleTap, and MouseWheel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.map.aspx